# What Headers and Data to Send With My Post Request

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Very beginner to web. I'm trying to login my router's configuration page which resides at 192.168.1.1 address. There is an authorization process and I inspected the post request being sent when logged in, via dev-tools of the browser. The "Form Data" includes these arguments:

```
Username: admin 
Password: pass 
action: login
```

Response code is 301 (Moved Temporarily) however, when I try to send a post request with python, the response code is 200 and the returned html prints the login layout. Also there are no cookies returned back except this "_TESTCOOKIESUPPORT=1". My code below:

```
import requests

data = {
    "Username": 'admin',
    "Password": 'pass',
    "action": 'login'
}

session = requests.session()
response = session.post("http://192.168.1.1", data=data)
print(response)
print(response.cookies)
```

Also when I run my code and refresh the login page from browser I get "wrong credentials" error from the page. What's wrong with my post request?

Comment: Could you use the browser tools to verify what address the form is posting data to?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis sure, it's like: `Host: 192.168.1.1 Origin: http://192.168.1.1 Referer: http://192.168.1.1/`
Actually when configuring on browser, address never changes so I guess all stuff being processed on javascript? I'm too new to be sure.

Comment: That's definitely the action tag on the html form element? And how is the POST data encoded? If you look in the network tab of your developer tools you should be able to select the POST request and view the request itself.

Comment: Do research into the paramiko python library. You're wanting to ssh into the router. Don't try to make a website that would give another user access to your router.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis yeah that's what I'm doing. Filtering the network tab as "method:POST" and viewing the request's itself. The inpult fields in the form element has ids like: Frm_Username, Frm_Password

Comment: @steveo314 I'm not building a webpage I'm just trying to log in programmatically